# UV Map color change

Tags: three.js

I have this UV map, it shows a black and white surface. Other Normal maps work fine. What is wrong with this one?
[image]

This one works as requested:
[image]

Where is the problem, are the colors incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is between object space normal mapping (1st image) and tangent space normal mapping (2nd image).

You can read more about it at http://www.surlybird.com/tutorials/TangentSpace/ and http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC4/Tangent+Space+Normal+Mapping

Comment: Thanks i don't know it.

Comment: What is best approach to generate terrain form this map in THEEE.js, to get geometry and use tangent space map (2nd image), or use space normal map?

Comment: Create for your terrain the second type of normal map.